# printing a split string

Tags: java, string, split

I am trying to print my string in the following format. `ua, login, login ---> ua, navigation, fault Average = 500 milliseconds`. I am storing the 2 strings into one string called `keyString` and putting it into the hashmap seperated by `"|"`. I am then splitting that when I am iterating over the keyset to get it in the format I originally stated but it is showing up like this `---> ua, ctiq, export|ua, ctiq export, transfer Average = 600 milliseconds`. Any ideas?

```
  public static void ProcessLines(Map<String, NumberHolder> uaCount,String firstLine, String secondLine) throws ParseException
   {
    String [] arr1 = firstLine.split("-- ", 2);
    String [] arr2 = secondLine.split("-- ", 2);
    String str1 = arr1[1];
    String str2 = arr2[1];


    ......
    String keyString = str1 + "|" + str2;               
    NumberHolder hashValue = uaCount.get(keyString);
     if(hashValue == null)
     {
        hashValue = new NumberHolder();
        uaCount.put(keyString, hashValue);                      
     }
     hashValue.sumtime_in_milliseconds += diffMilliSeconds;
     hashValue.occurences++;

     public static class NumberHolder
     {
      public int occurences;
      public int sumtime_in_milliseconds;       
     }
```

and heres the printing part

```
 for(String str : uaCount.keySet())
    {
        String [] arr = str.split("|",2);

        long average = uaCount.get(str).sumtime_in_milliseconds / uaCount.get(str).occurences;

        //System.out.println(str);

        System.out.println(arr[0] + " ---> " + arr[1] + " Average = " + average + " milliseconds");
    }
```

Comment: sorry I didn't put the code in at first please dont downvote

Comment: Why so many downvotes?

Comment: @Pshemo - probably because there was no code at first.  Lesson learned: post your code with your question.

Comment: To every @downvoter: ask OP for his code attempt first. If there wont be any then feel free to downvote. Make SO friendly place. +1 for balance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`split` uses regular expression to match place to split, and in "RegEx" `|` means OR. To use `|` as literal you need to escape it with `\` which in String is written as `"\\"`. Alternatively you can use `[|]`. Try

```
str.split("\\|",2);
```

Comment: that did the trick thank you. So moral of the story don't split the string with `"|"`?

Comment: @user2007843 there are no cons of using `|` as separator. You just need to know which characters are [meta-characters](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html#special) in regex so you would be able to match them with regex.